# Is it legal to have a query string with key names but not associated values (or equals signs)?

Tags: url, query-string

I'm trying to understanding the legalities of query params. Specifically, I'm curious if it's a hard-and-fast rule that the query string must be made up of key-value pairs or if it's technically valid to have a key-only.  No, I don't mean a key with an equals-sign then nothing after it.  I mean not even the equals-sign.  Just a key.

For instance 'demomode' in this example:

```
https://www.somesite.com/search?searchString=abc&demomode
```

Again, this is how I would *actually* do it...

```
https://www.somesite.com/search?searchString=abc&mode=demo
-or-
https://www.somesite.com/search?searchString=abc&demomode=1
-or-
https://www.somesite.com/search?searchString=abc&demomode=true
```

... and I am in no way promoting the first example above. I'm just curious.

I haven't been able to find anything that says if it's a hard-rule in the standard, a convention that people just agreed upon, or if it's more platform/parser specific, and therefore it depends.

Again, I am not encouraging this. Just curious.  It came about when looking at some code earlier that contained some pound-defines. You can pound-define something with a value, like `#define mode=4` then check for `4` later, but you can also simply pound-define something without giving it a value, such as `#define header_x` then simply check if that value is defined, not caring what the value is, or even if there is one in the first place.

Comment: [The current spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing) says Postelianly readers should treat it as equivalent to = and an empty value, but writers should not create it. I don't have the energy to track down history on this.

Comment: Perfect! @dave_thompson_085, if you move that to an answer, I'll mark it as such.